# How do I decide how many decimals, I should use for my float in c

Tags: c, floating-point

How do I decide how many decimals, I should use for my float. see i have this code`

```
int main (void)
{
    printf("please give me an integer: ");
    float num = GetFloat(); 

    float numb;  

    numb = num;
    numb = numb /2;

    printf("the half of %f is %f\n", num, numb);
}
```

but the computer prints out a lot of zeros after

eks:

> please give me an integer: **4**
>   the half of 4.000000 is 2.000000

So it could be nice like 3 decimals instead of 7:

> please give me an integer: **10**
>   the half of 10.0 is 5.00
>
> please give me an integer: **3**
>   the half of 3.00 is 1.50

Comment: A [`printf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) might help.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg  Designation of _3 decimals_ does not exist.

Comment: RTFM for [printf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also always use the `%g` format specifier. It formats the floating point number using either `f` or `e` format depending on the number of significant digits.

```
int main (void) {
    printf("Please give me a floating point number: ");

    // Read the value from the user.
    float num;
    scanf("%f", &num); 

    // Compute it's half.
    float half = num /2;

    // Display the result.
    printf("The half of %f is %g\n", num, half);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `printf` formatting parameters:

```
int main (void)
{
    printf("please give me an integer: ");
    float num = GetFloat(); 

    float numb;  

    numb = num;
    numb = numb /2;

    printf("the half of %.3f is %.3f\n", num, numb);

    return 0;
}
```

In the example the syntax `%.3f` tells `printf` to print 3 decimals.

Answer (score 0):

This is the format type for printf

```
%[flags][width][.precision][length]specifier
```

in this case you should have this `printf("the half of %.3f is %.3f\n", num, numb);`